# How can I send a form without leaving the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this registration form. How can I send the input information to the action.php without redirecting the user to it and after that redirecting it back to this page. I want the form to be submitted in the background.

```
<p id="message"></p>
<form action='action.php' method='post'>
Username: <input type='text' name='username'>
Password: <input type='password' name='password'>
e-mail: <input type='text' name='email'></div>
<input type='submit' value='Register' onclick='Submit()' />
</form>
<script>
function Submit(){
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "You have been successfully registered";
}
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: AJAX my friend, ajax :)

Comment: Can you show me how to use it?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: there are all kinds of resources out there Nikolay

Comment: can you show us what you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript post request like a form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
Should help you with this, here's an example that should work with the code you posted.

```
var data = $('form').serialize();
$.post( "action.php", data, function() {
    $('#message').text('You have been successfully registered');
})
```